# Springboot JPA query builder Cannot join to attribute of basic type

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, rest, jpa

I am trying to get the latest `Flight` on a specific airport of an `Aircraft` with Spring JPA query builder. The `Aircraft` data is managed in a different application.

```java
@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(schema = "schema1")
public class Flight implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(
            strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE,
            generator = "flight_sequence"
    )
    @SequenceGenerator(
            name = "flight_sequence",
            allocationSize = 1
    )
    @Column(nullable = false, updatable = false)
    private Long id;

    private Aircraft aircraft;
    private Date date;
    private String origin;
    private String destination;
}
```

```java
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(schema = "schema2")
public class Aircraft implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(
            strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE,
            generator = "aircraft_sequence"
    )
    @SequenceGenerator(
            name = "aircraft_sequence",
            allocationSize = 1
    )
    @Column(nullable = false, updatable = false)
    private Long id;
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="operator_id", nullable=false)
    private Operator operator;
    private String registration;
    private String acType;
    private Date createdAt;
    private Date updatedAt;
}
```

```java
public interface FlightRepository extends JpaRepository<Flight, Long> {
    Flight findFirstByDestinationAndAircraftRegistrationOrderByDateDesc(String destination, String registration);
}
```

But it throws this exception:
`org.hibernate.query.criteria.internal.BasicPathUsageException: Cannot join to attribute of basic type`

Answer (score 0):

You need to define association mapping for the `Aircraft` attribute of the `Flight` entity. Probably `ManyToOne` as you did for the `Operator` attribute of the `Aircraft` entity.

Comment: These two classes come from different databases and the `Aircraft` object is managed in a different application. Would this approach still work? After adding the annotations I'm getting this exception: `Use of @OneToMany or @ManyToMany targeting an unmapped class`